# Install both development and iTunes downloaded versions of the same app on one iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, provisioning, adhoc

I have an app in the App Store.  I would like to be able to have the production version of my app on my phone and install debug/test development builds of newer versions of the app.  I am using XCode 4 and it doesn't seem that this is possible.  I attempted to change the bundle identifier by adding some numbers at the end and that didn't work.  I also added the same numbers to my `${PRODUCT_NAME}` but that did not help either.  Is there a way to do this?  I'd prefer to not generate another App Id in the iOS Provisioning Portal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do it in Xcode 3 by setting different bundle name **${BUNDLE_NAME}** for a different identifier. plus different name, plus precompile instructions. Works well. Generate the ID, easy. I routinly produce 3 flavors of a build: development, release, and enterprise.

Comment: Can you please go into more detail about the changes you make?

Comment: In Xcode 3 we have build configuration profiles. You will need a separate profile for each build flavor, plus Release. In my case it's 3 (Dev,Enterprise, and Release). Dev and Release don't share **${BUNDLE_NAME}**  and others are different too.  `com.company.appname.dev` for Dev, and `com.company.appname` Release, and `com.company.appname.enterprise`(or adhoc). You can even share your keychain that way.

Comment: When I add .dev to the end of my Bundle Identifier I get the following when I try to run on my device  - [BEROR]Code Sign error: a valid provisioning profile matching the application's Identifier 'com.company.appname.dev' could not be found

Comment: @Brian did you register com.company.appname.dev id in the provisional portal?

Comment: I guess that's what I'm missing.  I only have the com.company.appname in the portal.  Actually its ####.com.company.appname.  So I would just need to add com.company.appname.dev and .adhoc if I want to have those.  That makes a little more sense.  I didn't want to create unnecessary App Ids, but since I'm chaining off of my existing app I guess it doesn't really matter.  Is this logic correct?  And then I will need create provisioning profiles for each the new app Ids for development or Ad Hoc distribution?  Thanks for helping me with this.

Comment: One more tip. Make sure your provisional profiles have different names too, otherwise your xcode will have troubles differentiating a proper provisional profile (surprisingly it resolves it by name, but suggests an appropriate one by apps bundle ID). learnt the hard-way.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  This has been a big help.  I'm not the team leader in the portal so I'll have to wait to try this out.  I'll update once I do.

Answer (score 0):

I found a great detailed answer [here](http://blog.chrismiles.info/2011/04/ios-dev-beta-production-builds.html).
The article describes how to automate the process of having different builds for production and development versions of an app, both in Xcode 3 and Xcode 4.